# Начало работы с vk api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу написать бота для вк. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Нужные мне библиотеки напросто отсутствуют. Или же я их неправильно подключаю.

Подскажите пожалуйста, откуда скачивать библиотеки и сам vk SDK?

Comment: А как вы их подключаете? Через maven?

Comment: Никак. Скачиваю библиотеки с интернета своими руками.